# Including text files in the published application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text, publish

I made an application with C# and it reads text files located on my hard drive but how do I publish the application and include these text files in the final exe so when the application is installed on a different computer it would work and not fail because it cannot locate the text files? I'm using Visual Studio2010

Answer (score 8):

In properties for the file in Visual Studio, change the Build Action from None (probably) to Content, or store it as a Resource file depending on where it needs to end up.

Of course if you are writing an installer just add it to the installed components.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you want, but you can do like this:

Create a folder, for example on your Desktop, and call it something, like MyProject.

Get the .exe file (from NameOfYourProject → bin → Debug → NameOfYourProject.exe) and put it into the folder togeather with the .txt file

(If you have your .txt file in a folder like Debug → myFolder → myTextFile you can just put the whole "myFolder"-folder in MyProject togeather with the .exe file)

Create a New → WinRAR ZIP-archive and call it something, like MyProject.zip and drag the "MyProject"-folder onto it.

Now you can upload the MyProject.zip anywhere and users can unzip the files on their computers.

This works but is probably not a decorous way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `<CopyToPublishDirectory/>` in your .csproj

```
<Content Include="YourPath\fileName.txt">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
          <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </Content>
```